# Why this makefile is not working?

Tags: gcc, compilation

I have two kinds of makefile for the same source code.
One is working but the other one is not working.
I write down makefile accoring to gnu guide.
But I cannot find out the reason why the 2nd makefile is not working.
Could you let me know the reason?
The final makefile what I want is to recompile only changed files.

1st makefile: working. but it compiles all files not changed files.

```
test:
        gcc -c test.c -o test.out
        gcc -c test2.c -o test2.out

clean:
        rm -rf test.out test2.out
```

2nd makefile: not working

```
all: program
program: test.o test2.o
        gcc test.o test2.o -o program

test.o: test.c
        gcc -c test.c
test2.o: test2.c
        gcc -c test2.c

clean:
        rm -rf test.o test2.out
```

**EDIT**
Working means that compile is successfully done.
When I try to compile source codes with 2nd makefile, there are many compile errors like below:

```
gcc test.o test2.o -o program
test2.o: In function `paths':
test2.c:(.text+0x1ca): multiple definition of `paths'
test.o:test.c:(.text+0x1d2): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 4 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 5 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 6 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 7 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 8 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 9 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 10 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 11 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 12 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 13 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 14 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 15 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 16 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 17 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 18 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 19 has invalid symbol index 21
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_line): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
test.o: In function `dead_code':
test.c:(.text+0xce): undefined reference to `some_func'
test.o: In function `reverse_negative':
test.c:(.text+0x150): undefined reference to `some_func'
test.o: In function `paths':
test.c:(.text+0x1fc): undefined reference to `some_other_function'
test.c:(.text+0x21d): undefined reference to `yet_another_function'
test.c:(.text+0x239): undefined reference to `do_some_things'
test2.o: In function `dead_code2':
test2.c:(.text+0xc6): undefined reference to `some_func2'
test2.o: In function `negative_returns2':
test2.c:(.text+0x109): undefined reference to `read2'
test2.o: In function `reverse_negative2':
test2.c:(.text+0x148): undefined reference to `some_func2'
test2.o: In function `paths':
test2.c:(.text+0x1f4): undefined reference to `some_other_function'
test2.c:(.text+0x215): undefined reference to `yet_another_function'
test2.c:(.text+0x231): undefined reference to `do_some_things'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [program] Error 1
```

Comment: What happens when you try to use the second Makefile?

Comment: Your first file is not producing any executable programs. Why do you think it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is the following:
In first `makefile` you are compiling 2 **separated** `object` files, and that's all.

> `command-line option -c is used to compile a source file to an object
>   file`,  also it's better to use `.o` extension instead of `.out` for
>   object files.

In second `makefile` you are trying to compile two object files the same way, but then you are trying to `link` them to executable.
And it's the main difference.
In this case `Linker` found `multiple definition of` and a lots of `undefined reference`

For object files it worked well, because when you compiling object files, you don't care about `unresolved references`, cause they may be resolved on linking stage